# Reactjs, search filter does not work correctly, when i load more users

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching the users data from dummyapi and i am listing them in the page. At beginning 15 users are listed and if you click the "load more" 15 more are listed. I have a search input, it filters the users by name. I am able to filter the first 15 users correctly. When i click load more and add 15 more users, it still filters only first 15 users. How can i fix this, can you help ?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import User from "./User";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const BASE_URL = "https://dummyapi.io/data/api";
  const APP_ID = "your app id";

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
  const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState(null);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(15);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const keyword = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredUsers =
      allUsers &&
      allUsers.filter((user) => user.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(keyword));
    setUsers(filteredUsers);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLimit(limit * 2);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/user?limit=${limit}`, {
          headers: { "app-id": APP_ID },
        });
        setUsers(response.data.data);
        setAllUsers(response.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [limit]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="filter">
          <h3 className="filter__title">USER LIST</h3>
          <div>
            <input
              id="filter"
              className="filter__input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by name"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="user__grid">
          {users &&
            users.map((user, index) => {
              const { id } = user;
              return <User key={index} id={id} />;
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="loadMore" onClick={handleClick}>
          <span>Load More</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you are getting the users from the server, you have to merge them with the current users in your state, see the code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/user?limit=${limit}`, {
          headers: { "app-id": APP_ID },
        });

        setAllUsers(prevState => {
          return [...prevState, response.data.data]
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [limit]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a couple issues.

1. You are basically storing duplicate data when you keep an original copy of the user data ***and*** a filtered copy. The filtered users are just derived data based on the user state and the current filter value. You should store the filtering value in state and do the filtering inline when rendering.
2. When new users are fetched, they are not added to the existing state.

Code Suggestions:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setSearch(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
};


useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/user?limit=${limit}`, {
        headers: { "app-id": APP_ID },
      });
      setUsers(users => users.concat(response.data.data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  fetchData();
}, [limit]);

...

{users.filter((user) => user.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(keyword))
  .map((user, index) => {
    const { id } = user;
    return <User key={index} id={id} />;
  })
}
```